# USB exclusive device

Tags: windows-7, usb

I want to only allow a given device to work on my windows 7 USB port. 
Anything else should not work when puggled on any of the USB ports.

Is there anyone who has had such need?

Comment: May be on linux box as well. I have a hibrid situation.

Comment: You can use UDEV rules on the linux box to forbid USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Windows 7 using policies.

http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/IT/archive/2010/02/07/windows-7-restricting-and-securing-usb-storage-devices.aspx